# Plotting relative frequency of every unique element of a dataframe

Tags: pandas, plot

How do I get from this dataset (NaNs are strings):

```
         0       1       2
0   item_1  item_2  item_3
1   item_1  item_2     NaN
2   item_2     NaN     NaN
3   item_1  item_2     NaN
4   item_2  item_3     NaN
```

Into this sorted relative frequency plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You need [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) + `value_counts` with `normalize=True`

```
df.replace('NaN',np.nan).stack().value_counts(normalize=True).plot(kind='bar')
```

---

[image]

From [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

> normalize bool, default False

> If True then the object returned will contain the relative frequencies of the unique values.